# Mongoose nested/deep populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I know this question has been asked a lot of times but I'm kind of new to mongodb/mongoose! Currently I am working on a MEAN stack for a medical software. The following is my schema:

```
var usersSchema = new Schema({
    _id      : {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId}
  //...
});
mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema);

var doctorsSchema = new Schema({
    _id      : {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId},
    userid      : {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Users' },
  //...
});
mongoose.model('Doctors', doctorsSchema);

var appointmentsSchema = new Schema({
  _id      : {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId},
  doctorids       : [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Doctors'} ]
  //...
});
mongoose.model('Appointments', appointmentsSchema);
```

**Nested Mongoose Populate**: How do I implement a nested mongoose populate on Appointments.find() in a way that  Appointments.find().populate('doctorids') should populate the array of Doctors and the array of Doctors in turn should populate the Users each Doctor points to. As per https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/wiki/3.6-Release-Notes#population they added Model.Populate! So I tried this but its NOT populating the Users inside the doctorids

```
Appointments
  .find({})
  .populate('doctorids')  // This is working
  .exec(function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(err);
      return;
    }
    Doctors //**Shouldn't this populate the doctors Users inside Doctors?**
      .populate(doc, {path: 'doctorids.userid'}, function(err, doc) {       
    }); 
    res.json({
      appointments: doc //Appointsments.Doctorids[].Userid is NOT populated
    });
});
```

[Edited: Moved the other questions to a new post @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412928/mongoose-nested-populate-sort-search-referenced-attributes ]

Answer (score 3):

There are many questions, I'm going to address only the deep population portion (the first question). (Also, I recommend you to split the question to multiple ones in case people have the answer to one but not all.)

While Mongoose supports nested population, you have to manually invoke `populate` on each model to be populated at every nested level. Alternative, you can use the [mongoose-deep-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate) plugin to do this (disclaimer: I'm the author of that plugin). For example, you can write this to populate doctors and users:

```
Apartments.find({}, function (err, apts) {
  Apartments.deepPopulate(docs, 'doctorids.userid', function (err, apts) {
    // now every `apt` instance has doctors and user
  })
})
```

You can also specify [Mongoose populate options](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) to control sort order for each populated path, like this:

```
var options = {
  doctorids: {
    options: {
      sort: '-name'
    }
  }
}
Apartments.deepPopulate(docs, 'doctorids.userid', options, cb)
```

Check out the plugin [documentation](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate) for more information.

Comment: Is it possible 3r level of population with deepPopulate?

Comment: @AralRoca yes, any level of depth.